# iReport - removing blank lines from field output

Tags: java, regex, jasper-reports, ireport, blank-line

I am trying to format a multi-line text field to remove blank lines in a report. After a bit of reading I have come up with the following regular expressions but the iReport compiler (not the editor as originally stated) won't accept these as valid and it throws a syntax error. Am I even close?

```
$F{followups}.replace("/^\s*\n/gm", "")
```

or

```
$F{followups}.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"")
```

Edit: as requested, the error message using the quoted expression (actually thrown during report compilation, not the editor) is:

> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Errors were encountered when compiling report expressions class file:
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
>   calculator_Footprints_1385543094268_580318: 218: unexpected char: '\' @ line 218, column 80.

Comment: Those are valid regex. Whats the syntax error? One is quoted (top) but not escaped `\`, try `"/^\\s*\\n/gm"`, the other isin't quoted. Both have `/` delimeters. Nail down the quoting first, then the delimeters. Try to get something valid first `"\\s"`, or `'\\s'`, or `'/\\s/'` or `"/\\s/"` or `/x/` or `"/x/"` or `x` or `"x"`, etc..

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more research and trial and error I found that the root cause of the problem was that the slashes needed double quoting ('\'), as **sln** hinted. Also, I ended up using a different syntax:

```
$F{followups}.replaceAll("(?m)^[ \\t]*\\r?\\n", "")
```